# How to bind to data thats not in my model using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I currently have a two tables.

```
Project
    int Number
    string Name
    List<WorkOrder> WorkOrders

WorkOrder
    int Number
    DateTime Date
    Project Project
```

I have a WPF window with a Master/Detail view using a ListView showing Projects and a DataGrid showing the WorkOrders wired up using MVVM and a single viewmodel. Everything works great but my coworkers want to make some changes. The first digit in the WorkOrder number corresponds to the type of material, i.e. 1=Wood, 2=Steel, 3=Plastic. They want the Project list to include the material categories to filter down the detail view.

```
Projects
 - 8888 - Some Project
   - Wood
   - Metal
   - Plastic
 - 9999 - Another Project
   - Wood
   - Metal
   - Plastic
```

Im just not sure how I databind to something that isn't in my data.  I created a TreeView and filled the material nodes using a Converter in my HierarchicalDataTemplate but there is nothing to bind to in my ViewModel to see what is selected from inside the ViewModel.  I hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance for our reply.

Comment: Er... how about adding a property to your view model to represent the selected item? You could bind this to the `TreeView.SelectedItem` property, although that is `read only`, so you'll need to set `Mode="One Way"` on your `Binding`.

Comment: What type would that property be?  If the user has one of the items selected thats not in the model how would I know what Project it belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

Dude, when you use MVVM, you're supposed to put *all* of the data that your view will require into your view model. You said that you added a collection of materials in a `TreeView` that represent the choice of materials... I'm assuming that you put that collection property into your view model.

All you need to do now is to add a link from the `TreeView.SelectedItem` property to a property on your `WorkOrder` object so that when the user selects a material, your binding to the `TreeView.SelectedItem` property will update the relevant property in your `WorkOrder` object.

You also said 'The first digit in the `WorkOrder` number corresponds to the type of material'... you'll need to change this if you want to use binding, so add a new property of type `Material` in your `WorkOrder` object. Then you'll be able to bind that property (of every instance of your `WorkOrder` type) to the `TreeView.SelectedItem` property.

Comment: The property in my View Model is just an IGrouping from a LINQ GroupBy(). Then the binding uses a Converter to convert the Groups in strings. So my property in the ViewModel is just a string and has no reference to the Project its located under in the ViewModel. I was hoping there was a trick to this but now I'm seeing that I'm going to have to wrap all my data in some kind of hierarchical class that I'll bind to the treeview.